# Vue 2 raw HTML bind to textarea

Tags: html, data-binding, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm creating an online text editor. I need to be able to get the users text from the textarea's tag, manipulate this text and bind it back to the textarea, but with HTML in it.

Example:

```
<textarea v-model="someText"></textarea>
```

Where `someText` is set to:

```
someText: '<b>bold</b>.. not bold'
```

and should display like: 
**bold**.. not bold

instead of: `<b>bold</b>.. not bold`

I have a feeling this isn't possible with the `textarea` tag, but what would be a way to do this?

Comment: Typically you would use `v-html`, but you are correct, inside `<textarea>` it will not matter (will not be **bold**).

Comment: Why don't you use the style section of your component to bold the text.

Comment: @altoin How? If I added a span tag and an ID the textarea would just display it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Typically you would use `v-html`, but you are correct, inside `<textarea>` the value will be raw, not processed (will not be bold).

To achieve what you want, maybe you could leverage the `contenteditable` property to create a `<html-textarea>`, as below.

```js
Vue.component('html-textarea',{
  template:'<div contenteditable="true" @input="updateHTML"></div>',
  props:['value'],
  mounted: function () {
    this.$el.innerHTML = this.value;
  },
  methods: {
    updateHTML: function(e) {
      this.$emit('input', e.target.innerHTML);
    }
  }
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    message: 'H<b>ELLO</b> <i>editable</i> Vue.js!'
  }
});
```

```css
div[contenteditable] { border: 1px solid lightblue; }
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<div id="app">
  <html-textarea v-model="message"></html-textarea>
  <hr>
  <div>
    Raw message: 
    <pre>{{ message }}</pre>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: When I go to update the `message`'s data `this.message='<span id="foo">bar</span>` I can see in the Vue devtool's console that the `message` is now updated, but the actual text and html does not display in the `html-textarea` tag. Any seggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: You mean you are updating the `message` *from the parent* after the initial creation?

Comment: Yes. However, I got the questions answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49809545/vue-model-not-updating/49809765#49809765).

Comment: @acdcjunior, I see you have experience with vue and `contenteditable`. Do you know how to insert components into `contenteditable`, store content from `contenteditable` to database and restore it later for editing? I mean functionality of simple wysiwyg with 'image' button which could insert `"some text <simple-image :src="/images/my-image.png" />"`.

Answer (score -1):

I'd have done it this way.

```
    <template>
     <div id="app">
    <form name="yourform">
      <textarea v-model="someText"></textarea>  
    </form>
    </div>
    </template>

    <script>
    export default {
    name: 'app',

     data () {
      return {
      someText: 'bold'
      }
      }

      }
     </script>

    <style scopped>
    textarea
    {
      font-weight:bold;
     }
    </style>
```

Comment: Right, but this bolds all the text inside textarea, not just parts of it.

Comment: Errm, yes, i'm not sure you can bold part of the text in a textarea, i think you'd need to use something like ckeditor to achieve that..