# Vue model not updating

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

When I try to update my custom text-area component's model data `this.message='<span id="foo">bar</span>` the text and html does not display in the htmltextarea tag like it should, but I can see the update applied in the Vue dev tool's console. I've also tried switching to an object instead of a string and using [Vue.set](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats), but this does not work either.

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

The goal with the `htmlTextArea` component is to get the users text from the htmlTextArea tag (this works), manipulate this text and bind it back to the textarea, but with HTML in it.

Custom text-area component:

```
<template>
  <div contenteditable="true" @input="updateHTML" class="textareaRoot"></div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  // Custom textarea 
  name: 'htmlTextArea',
  props:['value'],
  mounted: function () {
      this.$el.innerHTML = this.value;
  },
  methods: {
      updateHTML: function(e) {
          this.$emit('input', e.target.innerHTML);
      }
  }
}
</script>
```

Other component:

```
<template>
...
<htmlTextArea id="textarea" v-model="message"></htmlTextArea>
...
</template>
<script>
      data: {
        return {
          message: 'something'//this works
        }
      }
     ...
     methods: {
      changeText() {
        this.message='<span id="foo">bar</span>'//this does not
      }
     },
     components: {
         htmlTextArea
     }
</script>
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to set the value explicitly after the `value` props change. you can [watch](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#watch) for `value` change.

```
<template>
    <div contenteditable="true" @input="updateHTML" class="textareaRoot"></div>
</template>
<script>

export default {
  // Custom textarea
  name: "htmlTextArea",
  props: ["value"],
  mounted: function() {
    this.$el.innerHTML = this.value;
  },
  watch: {
      value(v) {
          this.$el.innerHTML = v;
      }
  },
  methods: {
    updateHTML: function(e) {
      this.$emit("input", e.target.innerHTML);
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: Actually I thought this worked, but now when I type into my textarea it types everything in reverse. So 'foo bar' becomes 'rab oof'. Any idea why?

Comment: Pls demo in js fiddle?

Comment: But the cursor will jump to the start of the paragraph after writing a word

Answer (score 4):

Change the `data` property into a function, as you have it defined it is not reactive.

```
data () {
    return {
        message: 'something'//this works 
    }
}
```

Now when you update the `message` property in your method, the component will update accordingly.

[Reactivity in depth](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html)

Comment: You are correct, however, I actually already had the return in there, I just didn't copy it over to here. It's still doesn't work though