# How to pass text with <b> tag having bold effect in <v-textarea> from the data() of vue app?

Tags: html, vue.js, vuetify.js, textarea

[image]

I am trying to pass text to v-textarea from data() in a vuetify project. The text inside the textarea appeears along with the bold tags which i dont want but instead i want the text to be in bold format.
But the text outside textarea is in bold.

```html
<template>
      <div>
        <v-textarea v-model="value"></v-textarea>
        <p v-html="value"></p>
      </div>
    </template>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      value: "<b>This is the value</b>",
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Vue 2 raw HTML bind to textarea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49214866/vue-2-raw-html-bind-to-textarea)

Comment: No i have tried that and it is not working.  i just want to output the text in a bold format in the text area instead of the <b> tags appearing in the output

Comment: Can you please check this in vuetify support forum. I did not think we can parse HTML inside v-model directly.

Comment: For best practice, I would keep all styles in classes + CSS. You can't partially style an input value that goes in textarea. If v-html doesn't work on textarea, then try to come up with a different solution, like the styled `<p>{{value}}</p>` turns into an input field on click.

Answer (score 0):

just move <b> from data value direct to the template

```
<template>
      <div>
        <v-textarea style="font-weight:bold" v-model="value"></v-textarea>
        <p><b>{{value}}</b></p>
      </div>
    </template>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      value: "This is the value",
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

and then configure textarea with css to be bold